# Error while running Mockito Spring test class

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

Hi this is my Test class

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = com.example.Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "localtest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:config/test-context.xml" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestingControllerTest {
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private ControllerApi capi;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(capi).build();
}

@Test
public void TestingHelloMethod() throws Exception {
MvcResult result = this.mockMvc
.perform(
get("/product/list")
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.content("[\r\n"
+ " \"id\": \"1122\",\r\n"
+ " \"description\": \"\",\r\n"
+ " \"name\": \"Abc\",\r\n"
+ " \"lastUpdate\": \"2021-12-20T01:51:51\",\r\n"
+ " \"bundledPop\": [\r\n"
+ " {\r\n"
+ " \"billing\": \"monthly\",\r\n"
+ " \"id\": \"\",\r\n"
+ " \"price\": {\r\n"
+ " \"value\": \"90.0\"\r\n"
+ " },\r\n"
+ " \"price\": \"recurring\",\r\n"
+ " \"recurringChargePeriodType\": \"monthly\"\r\n"
+ " }
")
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andDo(print())
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andReturn();

Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
}
```

When I run junit test case I get error. In the trace I can see it this way. I have searched a lot and tried to do changes as mentioned still getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 18, column 14:
service:
^ at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:890)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:379)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:248)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:602)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:165)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.comments.CommentEventsCollector$1.peek(CommentEventsCollector.java:59)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.comments.CommentEventsCollector$1.peek(CommentEventsCollector.java:45)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.comments.CommentEventsCollector.collectEvents(CommentEventsCollector.java:140)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.comments.CommentEventsCollector.collectEvents(CommentEventsCollector.java:119)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeScalarNode(Composer.java:221)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:191)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:313)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:304)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:288)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:195)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:313)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:304)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:288)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:195)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:313)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:304)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:288)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:195)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:115)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:135)
at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader$OriginTrackingConstructor.getData(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:99)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:84)
at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:36)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
... 69 more
```

when I trace it I get illegalStatementException saying failed to load application context. I am trying junit for first time I have no idea about it. I am trying to fix this since many days. Still getting issue. Please help me
How will I solve this issue. I have no idea of this

Comment: Why are you using ```@Springboottest``` and ```@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)``` ? 
Try using only @Springboottest

Tho your error appears to be in your stacktrace:
```Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 18, column 14:
service:
^ at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:890)
```
It appears that what ever you are trying to parse from your yaml file does not conform to the standards

Comment: 1. Add `@Autowired` to the `MockMvc` field. 2. Remove the `ControllerApi` field. 3. Remove `@WebAppConfiguration`, 4. Remove the `@ContextConfiguration` you already have `@SpringBootTest`.  5. Fix the error in your `application.yml` (or the context specific one).

Comment: yml error fixed. Made the changes as you said. Still getting same error.

Comment: Could you update your question with all the changes you made?